# Perl: HTML::TableExtract - How to get cell content which contains 3 <strong> tags?

Tags: perl

The above is my code to get parse something in the html table, I can get the cell, but I don't know how to get content in it, anyone could help? thanks!

```
my $te = new HTML::TableExtract( attribs => { id => 'friends' } );
$te->parse( $mech->content() ); #parse contents
my @tables = $te->tables;
my $table_count = scalar @tables;
print "tables count:$table_count\n";

my $table = $te->first_table_found;
print "table\n";
my @rows = $table->rows;

print "rows count:".scalar @rows."\n";
my $last_row=$rows[21];
print "last_row\n";

my $cell = $last_row->[2];
print "cell\n";

print $cell, "\n";
```

using the above code  `print $cell, "\n";`, I got:

```
SCALAR(0x12a4bc4)
```

and using this `print $cell->content_refs_list, "\n";`, I got:

```
Can't call method "content_refs_list" on unblessed reference
```

**Actual content in the cell:**

```
Page<strong>1</strong>/Total<strong>10</strong>Pages, <strong>100</strong>friends
```

Comment: Just a hint: `Use Data::Dumper; print Dumper $cell` might give more information than just 'scalar'.

Comment: @Konerak, thanks very much! I tried, there are a lot of `bless`es in the result, and more contents after them: .... 
....

'translation' => [],
'in_cell' => 0,
'count' => 2,
'rc' => 21,
'grid' => [
            [
              bless( {
                       '_parent' => bless( {....


how could I get the specific information I want?

Comment: BTW: i'm new to Perl, I only know the basic of perl

Comment: Please refer to http://search.cpan.org/~msisk/HTML-TableExtract-2.11/lib/HTML/TableExtract.pm#TABLE_METHODS

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to get `$cell`, you want to get `$cell->as_HTML` or `$cell->as_text`.

Accessing $cell directly, as you have learned, gets you a reference to the object. You presumably want the contents in some other more human-readable form.

Answer (score 0):

```
my $te = new HTML::TableExtract( attribs => { id => 'friends' } );
$te->parse( $mech->content() ); #parse contents
my @tables = $te->tables;
my $table_count = scalar @tables;
print "tables count:$table_count\n";

my $table = $te->first_table_found;

my $res = $table->cell(21,2);
print $res;
```

Comment: also please use `Use Data::Dumper;` and try using `print Dumper $cell` 
and `print Dumper(\$cell);`